automating terraform import using github actions
I am importing an aws lambda function created manually, now in to terraform. Since we have many env and regions we use terragrunt.
I was able to import the lambda function using module as:
resource "aws_lambda_function" "imported_lambda" {
   function_name = "myLambda"
}

Then I did terragrunt import with:
- name: Terragrunt import
  id: terragrunt_import
  uses: gruntwork-io/terragrunt-action@v2
  with:
    tf_version: ${{ github.event.inputs.tf_version }}
    tg_command: 'import'
    tg_version: ${{ github.event.inputs.tg_version }}
    tg_dir: target-repo
  env:
    AWS_SDK_LOAD_CONFIG: 1

My plan for next step was to do a terragrunt show as json and extract that json into a file. Then write a python script to read that json file and create a new module to manage this lambda function with terraform.
If I do: terraform show -json > myfile.txt using below step:
- name: Terragrunt show
  uses: gruntwork-io/terragrunt-action@v2
  with:
    tf_version: ${{ github.event.inputs.tf_version }}
    tg_command: 'show -json > myfile.txt'
    tg_version: ${{ github.event.inputs.tg_version }}
    tg_dir: target-repo
  env:
    AWS_SDK_LOAD_CONFIG: 1

It throws error that too many arguments.
Is there a way to extract all the imported resource (lambda) into a text file so that I read it using python?

You might try with terraform/terragrunt state list. The show switch requires you to specify the resource name.

@MarkoE what i need is to extract properties of the imported resource. Information like:
tags, arn, runtime, logging_config, memory_size etcetera.
Then based on this info, I will create a module to manage this imported lambda function
I dont see how terraform/terragrunt state list can help at all for this

Then you need terraform/terragrunt state show aws_lambda_function.imported_lambda.

@MarkoE thats what I tried and its in the question as well. I just cant get it to export the output of the terraform show into a file.
It throws error that too many arguments.

Is this where you say you tried it 'show -json > myfile.txt'? I'm not sure if you can use it this way. Maybe redirect it to the GH output.

@MarkoE with gruntwork-io/terragrunt-action@v2 I dont think there is too much we can do with "show" command.
do you know a way to extract the output

I'd try using show -json as the command and then referencing the action's tg_action_output output from a following step, either writing it to a file or using it as is.

@Ngenator I tried the tg_action_output with show -json. and it worked like magic. thank you so much... this resolved my issue
could you edit your message and post it as an answer, so I could accept it?

I'd try using show -json as the command and then referencing the action's tg_action_output output from a following step, either writing it to a file or using it as is.
Something like:
- name: Terragrunt show
  id: terragrunt_show
  uses: gruntwork-io/terragrunt-action@v2
  with:
    tf_version: ${{ github.event.inputs.tf_version }}
    tg_command: 'show -json'
    tg_version: ${{ github.event.inputs.tg_version }}
    tg_dir: target-repo
  env:
    AWS_SDK_LOAD_CONFIG: 1

- run: 'echo ${{ steps.terragrunt_show.outputs.tg_action_output }}'

